# Yii2 : Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php, yii2

**My controller :**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model = new CreateBookings();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
            {
                $imageName = $model->primary_name;
                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
                $model->id_image = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                $model->save();

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else 
            {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }

    }
```

Getting this error on submitting my form, dont know what's wrong with it..
 Tried with `$model->save(false);` ..but not working as well

Comment: are records saving in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `getPrimaryKey()` method:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
            $model = new CreateBookings();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
            {
                $imageName = $model->primary_name;
                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
                $model->id_image = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                if($model->save())
                {

                   $lastInsertID = $model->getPrimaryKey();
                   return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $lastInsertID]);
                }
               else
               {
                   // print_r($model->getErrors()); => check whether any validation errors are there
               }


            } else 
            {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }

    }
```

Comment: how can i redirect to another model if i don't have id for view file

Comment: @CrazzySkulll: I didnt get you. you can simply check whether records exists or not and accordingly redirect to another view

Comment: solved by myself. just passed my view file from another model and used fk.